# Cannot save custom metabox data

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I have made a custom metabox in a custom post type. My custom metabox includes two radio buttons. But no matter what I do, I'm not able to save data in my database. Wordpress saves it's data in the "wp_postmeta" but not the custom data that I wanted to save. Here's my code:

```
function wp_add_custom_meta_boxes(){
    add_meta_box("custom_meta", "Settings", "wp_meta_box_callback", "images", "normal");
}
add_action("add_meta_boxes", "wp_add_custom_meta_boxes");

function wp_meta_box_callback($post){
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), "wp_custom_image_nonce");
    ?>

    <div class="meta-row">
        <div class="meta-th">
            <p>Should this image show on the main page ?</p>
        </div>    
        <div class="meta-td">
            <label for="yes">Yes</label>
            <input id="yes" type="radio" name="on_mainpage" value="true">
            <label for="no">No</label>
            <input id="no" type="radio" name="on_mainpage" value="false">
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
}

function wp_save_meta_info($post_id){
    if(!wp_verify_nonce("wp_custom_image_nonce", basename(__FILE__))){
        return;
    }
    if(defined("DOING_AUTOSAVE") && DOING_AUTOSAVE){
        return $post_id;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['on_mainpage'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, "show_on_mainpage", $_POST['on_mainpage']);
    }
}

add_action("save_post", "wp_save_meta_info");
```

I have 1 more question. Does update_post_meta() requires some existing data in the database to be updated or does it automatically saves the data in the database if it doesn't exists ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your update post meta function

```
function wp_save_meta_info($post_id){
    if(!wp_verify_nonce($_POST["wp_custom_image_nonce"], basename(__FILE__))){
        return;
    }
    if(defined("DOING_AUTOSAVE") && DOING_AUTOSAVE){
        return $post_id;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['on_mainpage'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, "show_on_mainpage", $_POST['on_mainpage']);
    }
}
```

Also just to point out there is a custom save_post hook for custom post types

the hook is called -- `save_post_yourpostypename` so

```
add_action("save_post_posttype", "wp_save_meta_info");
```

Otherwise you will need to check its the correct post type within the function, or have unique nonce names throughout your custom post types. Also i'd recommend using a different action for your nonces, something descriptive and unique would be better if you are debugging some time in the future

`update_post_meta()` will create a meta entry for your field name if it doesn't exist so developers prefer it to add_post_meta() when there should only be 1 meta entry for that field name, i.e. the data should be updated on post save rather than a new meta entry created. You can see your postmeta entries on the postmeta db table.

Comment: No @David. I tried using update_post_meta() when the data wasn't in the database and guess what ? It didn't worked at all. So what I did is, I used add_post_meta() to enter data in the database if it doesn't exits but if it does then I used update_post_meta() to update that post meta data and now it works perfectly. The only problem that I'm getting is with the nonce field. The wp_verify_nonce() isn't working for me. Any idea why ?

Comment: im 100% it does create a meta field, im using it now in code (its also on the function explanation page) you may have had other issues....sorry i spotted the nonce issue earlier and forgot to mention, i've updated above, you need to pass the value in $_POST to it rather than just the name.